# web api call performance tuning

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to figure find why my api is taking ~5 secs working on 1000 records,is that good or bad?I want to know what tools are there in asp.net webapi to figure out which piece of code or where its consuming time and fine tune the performance

[image]

CODE:-

```
    List<LookaheadRunInfo> lookaheadRunsInfo = new List<LookaheadRunInfo>();
    List<lookahead_run> lookaheadRunData = new List<lookahead_run>();

    if (!filterCriteria.labeled)
    {
        lookaheadRunData = bitDB.lookahead_run.Where(x => x.lookahead_run_status == null && x.submission_time != null).OrderByDescending(x => x.submission_time).Skip(filterCriteria.PageNumber * filterCriteria.PageSize).Take(filterCriteria.PageSize).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        lookaheadRunData = bitDB.lookahead_run.OrderByDescending(x => x.submission_time).Skip(filterCriteria.PageNumber * filterCriteria.PageSize).Take(filterCriteria.PageSize).ToList();
    }
    foreach (var lookaheadRunRow in lookaheadRunData)
    {
        var lookaheadRunInfo = new LookaheadRunInfo();
        var lookaheadRunId = lookaheadRunRow.lookahead_run_id;
        lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink = lookaheadRunRow.ec_job_link;
        lookaheadRunInfo.UserSubmitted = lookaheadRunRow.submitted_by;
        lookaheadRunInfo.SubmittedTime = lookaheadRunRow.submission_time.ToString();
        lookaheadRunInfo.RunStatus = lookaheadRunRow.lookahead_run_status;
        var completionTime = lookaheadRunRow.completion_time;
        if (completionTime == null)
        {
            lookaheadRunInfo.ElapsedTime = (DateTime.UtcNow - lookaheadRunRow.submission_time).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            lookaheadRunInfo.ElapsedTime = (lookaheadRunRow.completion_time - lookaheadRunRow.submission_time).ToString();
        }
        List<String> gerrits = new List<String>();
        List<string> lookaheadRunChangeListIds = new List<string>();

        if (!filterCriteria.labeled)
        {
            lookaheadRunChangeListIds = (from lrcl in bitDB.lookahead_run_change_list
                                         join cl in bitDB.change_lists on lrcl.change_list_id equals cl.change_list_id
                                         where lrcl.lookahead_run_id == lookaheadRunId
                                         //and cl.change_list_id not in (select clcl.change_list_id from component_labels_change_lists as clcl)
                                         //where !(from clcl in bitDB.component_labels_change_lists select clcl.change_list_id).Contains(cl.change_list_id)
                                         where !bitDB.component_labels_change_lists.Any(clcl => clcl.change_list_id == cl.change_list_id)
                                         select cl.change_list.ToString()).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            lookaheadRunChangeListIds = (from lrcl in bitDB.lookahead_run_change_list
                                         join cl in bitDB.change_lists on lrcl.change_list_id equals cl.change_list_id
                                         where lrcl.lookahead_run_id == lookaheadRunId
                                         select cl.change_list.ToString()).ToList();
        }
        //bitDB.Log = Console.Out;
        //lookaheadRunInfo.gerrits = gerrits;

        lookaheadRunInfo.gerrits = lookaheadRunChangeListIds;

        if (lookaheadRunChangeListIds.Count != 0 && filterCriteria.labeled == false)
        {
            lookaheadRunsInfo.Add(lookaheadRunInfo);
        }
        else if (filterCriteria.labeled == true)
        {
            lookaheadRunsInfo.Add(lookaheadRunInfo);
        }
    }
   return lookaheadRunsInfo;
```

Comment: That is way to long for 5 records. You will need to shared your code that queries that data for us to help you. Additionally this issue may be missing indexes etc in your database, not your code.

Comment: @Kyle,its for 1000 records,is there some sort of profliling I can add to my code to see where its taking more time

Comment: You really need to start with reviewing your C# code that creates the SQL query, from there step through your code and copy the generated SQL or run SQL profiler on your SQL server to get the query. Then run that same query in SQL Server Management Studio. If it runs faster in SSMS then from your code you have a code issue. If it is about the same it is still a toss up between your code and missing indexes etc. If you are willing to share some of your code I can help identify if there are any obvious code flaws in your query.

Comment: @Kyle - I updated my question with the code,it uses Entity framework query

Comment: You are doing quite a bit in the foreach loop you run the results through after getting the data back (not uncommon). I would imagine that all that extra work is responsible for some of the issue. You actual EF query is clean, so you may need some indexes in your database to improve performance. If you get the entity framework generated SQL and run it directly in SSMS that will tell you a lot about speed and can help identity where you may need indexes.

Comment: Hi Kyle,how do I get the entity framework generated SQL?is there a way?can you exactly tell what should I change in the code to get generated SQL?

Comment: if you temporarily take off the ToList() at the end of your EF query (this will allow it to stay an IQueryable), then dubug the code and have a breakpoint on that line, once on the line when you hover over it will show you the EF generated SQL query that is actually being run.

Comment: okay,I will check that,also is there a simple way to know if my table or database is indexed or not,am using MYSQL

Comment: use SQL profiler for the database to see all the queries that hit the database. Once you have the query, use query execution plan tool of SSMS to see what takes what amount of time